# Converting SqlDataReader column values to json string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, ado.net

I'd like to output a string (or possibly other variable type if string isn't ideal) based on the output of a SQLDataReader read. I have been playing around with the "while" loop,  `while (reader.Read())`

I need to end up with something I can serialize with json.net.

Here's my current code - it outputs to debug log just to make sure I was successfully reading from the database.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString = "Data Source =.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = TeamProject; Integrated Security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True";

        string querystring = "RosterMake";

        using (SqlConnection connection = 
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querystring, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}",
                    reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);

                    //  What do I put here to make the results something I can 
                    //  serialize with json.net???

                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("oops");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and.. if you dont use sqldatareader, use `SqlDataAdapter.Fil`l a `DataTable`, DataTable is easy to convert to xml

Comment: What has this question to do with `SqlDataReader`? Isn't it just about how to convert a string to a json object? You're showinjg a lot of code but actually you are asking for a json tutorial.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json will help you, just need to create a class that represents needed JSON format, and then fill List<YourClass>  with reader[i] values

Comment: @TimSchmelter The issue here is storing it somewhere i can access it with json.net. Unless you know of a way to pass the `SQLDataReader` straight to json... I just don't know what the best way to store it so I can serialize it later.

Comment: @KeltonCrouse: a `SqlDataReader` reads data which comes from a database and gives you an object. It has methods like `reader.GetString(0)` that gives you already the right type. But you have to process this string yourself, there is no automatism of the datareader. But haveyou tried this:`JObject.Parse(reader.GetString(0))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` to hold the values and serialize it. The `Newtonsoft.Json` will serialize it as a simple json. See the code as an example and the comments:

```
// define the list
var values = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
try
{
    connection.Open();
    // Use the using block to make sure you are disposing the dataReader object.
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        do
        {               
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // define the dictionary
                var fieldValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                // fill up each column and values on the dictionary                 
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    fieldValues.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
                }

                // add the dictionary on the values list
                values.Add(fieldValues);

            }
        } while (reader.NextResult());   // if you have multiple result sets on the Stored Procedure, use this. Otherwise you could remove the do/while loop and use just the while.
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("oops");
}
```

Now you can serialize the `values` using `JsonConvert.Serialize(values)` and you will get it as a json like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "John", Age: 30, Sex: "M"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Maria", Age: 28, Sex: "F"
    }
]
```

Comment: how does this work if the shape of the recordsets are different, in the case of multiple-recordsets?

Comment: Because it can be deserialized to a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`.

Comment: so you get two arrays?

Comment: A Dictionary is a key-pair value data structure. It will be deserializating a single object like `{ name: 'Charles', lastName: 'Okwuagwu` }`. `string` is the proeprty name and `object` is the value. the value must be `object` beacuse it can be a `string`, `number`, etc.. Given you have a list on the json, then you define a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` for many objects. That's why it works.

Comment: Thanks, I found an alternative. I use `WriteStartArray();` and `WriteEndArray();` to delimit each NextResult(); into separate arrays

Answer (score 5):

It's simple to convert SqlDataReader to JSON. The thing to have is Newtonsoft.Json; Library Here is Example

```
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //sqlDatoToJson(rdr);
            var datatable = new DataTable();
            datatable.Load(rdr);
            string JsonResponse = string.Empty;
            JsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datatable);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("3");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rdr);
            con.Close();
            return new JsonResult() { Data = JsonResponse,JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `GetString()` method on the `SqlDataReader`. You want something like this:

```
string myString;

using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    do
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            myString = rdr.GetString(0);
        }
    } while (rdr.NextResult());
}
```

Note this just blindly reads strings until there's nothing left. It's up to you to put the logic in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can return a list:

```
 public List<EnEntity> methodname(string pParam1)
    {
        try
        {
            List<EnEntity> ListEntity = new List<EnEntity>();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_name", conexion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@vParam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pParam1;

            SqlDataReader drd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (drd.HasRows)//!=null
            {
                int pos_iIndex = drd.GetOrdinal("iColumnaName");
                while (drd.Read())
                {
                    EnEntity oEnEntity = new EnEntity();

                    oEnEntity.iPropertie = drd.IsDBNull(pos_iIndex) ? 0 : drd.GetInt32(pos_iIndex);

                    ListEnEntity.Add(oEnEntity);
                }
                drd.Close();

            }
            return (ListEnEntity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It will be better if all variables and methods will be named in English, otherwise they meaning is a mystery for those who do not understand worlds like :
ListarReporteSegunPeriodoFecha

Comment: i did, i hope this help you